# WCF Expected Element 'Stream', Encountered Element name 'Binary'

Tags: c#, wcf, stream, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I am trying to troubleshoot certain requests that are making it into a WCF service call that we setup specifically for a customer that claims they can only send a HTTP POST with form encoded parameters in the request body.

To handle this, we setup an API call that looks like the following:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UrlTemplate = "/CustomCall")]
CustomCallResponse CustomCall(Stream input)
```

We were able to test this with fiddler and it worked by using **content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded** and putting the post data in the request body in the format

```
param1=value1&param2=value2
```

As I said, this worked for our test.

Our logging system is catching errors when they post into our system that is giving us the following error message:

```
Message: Expecting element 'Stream' from namespace  'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO'.. Encountered 'Element' with name 'Binary', namespace ''. 
StackTrace: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Expecting element 'Stream' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO'.. Encountered 'Element' with name 'Binary', namespace ''. 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
```

I have used WCF enough that I have seen this message several times, and its typically related to a contract mismatch. However, the expected parameter for this **Stream** was working when we tried it, and I am not sure what they are doing or how to reproduce this issue.

Any ideas on what might be causing this, or how to try to reproduce this to get the same error so that I can handle it and fix it?

Comment: If you turn on logging you will be able see the information you need to determine the source of the problem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the leverage to convince them to turn on this level of logging in our production environment, thus why I am trying to find a needle in a haystack and reproduce. I agree, this def would be my go-to.